# Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core doesn't Restore with NETStandard20

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, botframework, .net-standard-2.0

I've got a NetStandard20 project [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure) that pulls in storage dependencies to Azure (CosmosDB, Storage.Common, Blob). I'm on the latest version of each of those dependencies.

No matter what I've tried, I get this warning on build:

```
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.    Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure C:\git\botbuilder-dotnet\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.csproj
```

Now, from what I can tell, the Nuget package for Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common seems to support NetStandard2. Via [Nuget.Org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/):

```
.NETStandard 2.0
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core (>= 1.0.0)
NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.1)
Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2)
```

Likewise, Keyvault.Core says it supports NetStandard > 1.6.1 ([Nuget Link here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core/))

This has been bugging me for ages! What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As the warning shows that you install the package [Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core/1.0.0) which has no dependencies.

I suggest that you could install `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core` at version **3.0.3** to follow [SEMVER conventions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/837).

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/834).

Comment: The problem is that I don't install the package. My project has no direct reference. It's a transitive dependency being pulled through from the Azure dependencies.

Comment: This is the best solution until a new version is released which uses a more recent version of `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core`

Answer (score 1):

The KeyVault.Core package ( [GitHub Repo here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/src/SDKs/KeyVault/data-plane) ), picked up as a transitive dependency of the Azure Storage libraries doesn't yet support NetStandard20. I confirmed with the Azure Storage team that this warning is fine, and can be suppressed.

> [12:20 PM] (Azure SDK Owner) So, our only dependency on that is the
>   definitions of two interfaces, which are stable.  Not the
>   implementation.  The warning should be ignorable in that case.

It does appear the Azure SDK team is "in-process" of supporting NetStandard20 as seen in [this Commit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/commit/b0d42d14bfe92a24996826b2487ba592e644f581).

We cannot apply the no-warn suppression directly to the package links below as they're not picked up across transitive dependencies. See [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5740) for details.

The result: I've had to suppress this warning for the entire assembly:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1701</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```